# Why is this shared Angular service data not showing up?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm new to Angular, and my guess is I don't understand $resource and promises enough.

I'm trying to create a shared data scenario where I have a retrieval service that gets data fresh from a web api, and a shared service which my controllers can bind to for working with the data.

However, the data I'm expecting to display in the controller line `vm.lines = sharedService.getLines(this.id);` never gets displayed even though I can see that the web api is delivering the data to the retrievalService.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction here?

**Data Retrieval service:**

```
module services {
    "use strict";

    export interface IRetrievalService {
            getLines(id: string): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IResource>;
        }

    interface IResource extends ng.resource.IResource<app.ILine> { }

    export class RetrievalService implements IRetrievalService {

        static $inject = ['$resource'];
        constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {

        }

        getLines(id: string): angular.resource.IResourceClass<IResource> {
            return this.$resource("api/myUrl/?id=" + id);
        }
    }

    angular
        .module("services")
        .service("app.services.retrievalService", RetrievalService );
}
```

**Shared Service**

```
module services {
    "use strict";

    export interface ISharedService {
        _lines: app.ILine[];
        getLines(id: string): app.ILine[];
    }

    export class SharedService implements ISharedService {
        _lines: app.ILine[];

        static $inject = ["app.services.retrievalService"];
        constructor(private dataService: app.services.DataService) {

        }

        getLines(id: string): app.ILine[] {
            if (!this._lines) {
                var resource = this.dataService.getLines(id);
                resource.query((data: app.ILine[]) => {
                    this._lines = data
                });
            }

            return this._lines;
        }
    }

    angular
        .module("services")
        .service("app.services.sharedService", SharedService);
}
```

**Controller/Component**

```
module app {
    "use strict";

    interface ILinesScope {
        id: string;
        lines: app.ILine[];
    }

    class LinesComponentController implements ILinesScope {
        id: string;
        lines: app.ILine[];

        static $inject = ["app.services.sharedService"];
        constructor(private sharedService: services.SharedService) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.id = "5";
            vm.lines = sharedService.getLines(this.id);
        }
    }

    class LinesComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
        templateUrl = "app/Lines.html";
        controllerAs = "vmLines";
        controller = ["app.services.sharedService", LinesComponentController];
    }

    angular.module("app")
        .component("myLines", new LinesComponent());
}
```

**html**

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>column 2</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="line in vmLines.lines">
            <td>{{line.col1}}</td>
            <td>{{line.col2}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to follow advice from [John Papa](https://johnpapa.net/sharing-data-in-an-angular-controller-or-an-angular-service/) at for how to do shared data across controllers.

**UPDATE WITH FULL SOLUTION**
Here are the changes I had to make to get this to work:

**Shared Service:**

```
module services {
    "use strict";

    export interface ISharedService {
        //_lines: app.ILine[];
        _lines: ng.resource.IResourceArray<ng.Resource.IResource<ILine>>
        //getLines(id: string): app.ILine[];
        getLines(id: string): ng.resource.IResourceArray<ng.Resource.IResource<ILine>>

    }

    export class SharedService implements ISharedService {
        //_lines: app.ILine[];
        _lines: ng.resource.IResourceArray<ng.Resource.IResource<ILine>>

        static $inject = ["app.services.retrievalService"];
        constructor(private dataService: app.services.DataService) {

        }

        //getLines(id: string): app.ILine[] {
        getLines(id: string): ng.resource.IResourceArray<ng.Resource.IResource<ILine>> {
            var vm = this;
            if (!this._lines) {
                var resource = this.dataService.getLines(id);
                return resource.query();
                //resource.query((data: app.ILine[]) => {
                //    this._lines = data
                //});
            }

            return this._lines;
        }
    }

    angular
        .module("services")
        .service("app.services.sharedService", SharedService);
}
```

**Controller/Component:**

```
module app {
    "use strict";

    interface ILinesScope {
        id: string;
        //lines: app.ILine[];
        lines: ng.resource.IResourceArray<ng.Resource.IResource<ILine>>;
    }

    class LinesComponentController implements ILinesScope {
        id: string;
        //lines: app.ILine[];
        lines: ng.resource.IResourceArray<ng.Resource.IResource<ILine>>;

        static $inject = ["app.services.sharedService"];
        constructor(private sharedService: services.SharedService) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.id = "5";
            vm.lines = sharedService.getLines(this.id);
        }
    }

    class LinesComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
        templateUrl = "app/Lines.html";
        controllerAs = "vmLines";
        controller = ["app.services.sharedService", LinesComponentController];
    }

    angular.module("app")
        .component("myLines", new LinesComponent());
}
```

Comment: Can you share the html/view? If as you are saying you see `vm.lines` populated with the retrieved data then it would be interesting to see your display method.

Comment: I know the html is right because before I tried to implement the shared service it was displaying data from the retrieval service. I'll post it though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you need to return `$resource.query` from your service.

```
getLines(id: string): app.ILine[] {
   if(!this._lines) {
      var resource = this.dataService.getLines(id);
      return resource.query((data: app.ILine[]) => {
         this._lines = data
      });
   }
   return this._lines;
}
```

Comment: But what I want is to return the data only from the shared service. I don't want it to re query the data from the api. If I have that function return 'resource.query',then it can't return just the array of lines.

Comment: `$resource.query` returns an array, and later populates it when the data has come back. So either way it's returning an array. It's just the one coming from `$resource.query` has a few extra properties it adds onto it.

Comment: OK, good. So does that mean then that in the controller I have to change it to use $promise?

Comment: is returning the `resource.query` going to break the typescript compilation though since `getLines` is typed as an `app.ILine[]` ?

Comment: it does break the typescript compile. So when I fix all those types in the service, my controller which expects the ILine[], now wants IResourceArray<ILinesResource>

That's why I was wondering about $promise

Comment: I haven't really done any work in typescript, but I'm guessing you can just cast the result of `$resource.query`. If you're having to work with promises a lot still with `$resource`, it defeats the purpose of using it.

Comment: Ok, this was correct. I had to make some changes I will reflect in an update to my question. Thanks DerekMT12!

Answer (score 1):

when you breakpoint `this._lines = data` does debugger hit it?  This kind of reminds me of the common issue where `this` is undefined.  You may need to do `var self = this` outside of the callback function and then say `self._lines = data`

Comment: data in data? or data in this and this._lines?

Comment: I can see it in data, yes

Comment: I added var self = this, and now it is defined as the dataService. But data is still not getting to the controller or view

Comment: Although this wasn't the direct solution, it wouldn't have worked without this. Thank you Brendon Colburn!